# MATLAB For loop optimization

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I'm completely new to MATLAB, and I still don't know the functions and way of programming with it.

I have a 3D matrix : 19*1000*134 with data that I want to filter with a butterworth.
I did a code with a double for loop that works perfectly well:

```
%% Filtering
w1 = 1/(fs/2);
w2 = 45/(fs/2);
[b, a] = butter(6, [w1 w2], 'bandpass');

for i=1:channel
    for j=1:nb_epoch
        Data_filtered(i,:,j) = filtfilt(b, a, s_EEG.data(i,:,j));
    end
end
```

Is there any other way of doing the same thing better or not ? Since I don't know MATLAB, I'm not sure it's the best way of implementing this bandpass filter.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds about right.

Comment: There is a [FiltFiltM](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32261-filterm?focused=5193423&tab=function) function at FEX. The advantage is, that it is able to  processes a matrix along a certain dimension. However I am not sure how much faster this would be

Comment: FYI, the selected answer below will not run as written.  You are not allowed to run nested `parfor` loops.

Comment: Yep it's noticed. I only used one, and it's quite nice. thanks every one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only optimization I can figure out is using parfors:

```
w1 = 1/(fs/2);
w2 = 45/(fs/2);
[b, a] = butter(6, [w1 w2], 'bandpass');

parfor i=1:channel
    parfor j=1:nb_epoch
        Data_filtered(i,:,j) = filtfilt(b, a, s_EEG.data(i,:,j));
    end
end
```

Keep in mind that the first time you run parfors, since the workers pool is empty, the script will be much much slower because workers must be instantiated and initialized. Multithreading should help.

Comment: Could you explain me what are parfor ? What is the workers pool ? I'm trying to get a working knowledge on Matlab and it would be really usefull for me.

Comment: Parfors are nothing but for-loop iterations executed in a multithreading context. To simplify, this means that the task is splitted into multiple subtasks, and each Matlab worker is assigned to a subtask. For detailed infos: https://it.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html

Comment: But then, if you divide the task in multithread, I can understand it would be faster, but then why is it slower the first time we run it ? What would happen if you run it once, then again with 2 others loop on an other set of data ?

Comment: And since the parfor is not executing the loop in a deterministic way, does it means the data that was position (4 , : , 25) could be filtered and placed at the position (18 , : , 130) ?

Comment: The first time Matlab encounters a parfor, it must create the workers. This process takes very long time. Once they are created, they are ready to take care of all your parfor-loops as long as you don't shut down Matlab. When you close Matlab, workers are destroyed.

Comment: Since your loop insert results into an array using i and j indexes, there is no risk that the data will be misplaced. This can occur if you just append results on the bottom of an array without specific indexing. Parfors in which the inner loop data depends on the outer loop data, or vice-versa, will throw an exception... but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Ok thanks that's very clear ! One last question on the misplacing. It means that MatLab is able to create position (5, :, 1) before the position (4, :, 1). Or on a 2D level, it can create colum 5 before colum 4 ?

Comment: Yes this can happen, but as long as you index everything, this is absolutely not a problem :)

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo  https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nested-parfor-loops-and-for-loops.html   You can not nest `parfor` loops.  So you will have to switch one of the loops back to a regular `for` loop.  You will probably get the best speed by making the outer loop a `parfor` and the inner a regular `for`